# Handling relative path when insert third party javascript

Tags: javascript, path

I'm building a third party javascript widget. The script is loaded with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var getHTML = function ( url, callback ) {

if ( !window.XMLHttpRequest ) return;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function() {
if ( callback && typeof( callback ) === 'function' ) {
    callback( this.responseXML );
}
}

xhr.open( 'GET', url );
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.send();

};
getHTML( 'https://example.com', function (response) {document.getElementById("root").innerHTML=response.documentElement.innerHTML;
});
</script>
```

The HTML contained a JS file :

```
<script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
```

and a CSS file :

```
<link href="/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When those 2 scripts are loaded, I'm expecting that the finals urls will be "https://example.com/static/js/main.js" and "https://static/css/main.css" but I'm having "https://container-website.com/static/js/main.js" and "https://container-website.com/static/css/main.css".

I prefer not to use absolute path for the JS and CSS file (I'm using create-react-app to generate the build). Any others methods ?

Comment: If source is another domain you have to use absolute url. Browser has no way to guesss where it should come from. Might be able to use environment variables to help out and build the proper url. Not really enough known for a properly detailed answer

Comment: Thx ! I guess I should check how to generate absolute path with create-react-app